# Activate child only if parent is active in a Hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a hierarchical structure of department in sql using table.I have included the feature of Activation & Deactivation of department.

Now I want that if anyone wants to activate child then its parent should be activated or else it should return -11.

I have made a procedure but its not working for @Is_Active flag ='Y' where this 'Y' is supplied that child should be activated through procedure.

```
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here   
ALTER PROCEDURE DepartmentSetStatus(@DEPARTMENT_ID nvarchar(1000), @Is_Active char(1))  

--[DepartmentSetStatus] "1",'Y'  

AS  
BEGIN  
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  

-- interfering with SELECT statements.  
declare @count int  

SET NOCOUNT OFF;  


if @Is_Active='Y'  
begin  


 WITH Vals1 AS (  
   SELECT *  
   FROM [I_DEPARTMENT]  
   WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID in (select Data from  dbo.Split(@DEPARTMENT_ID,','))  

   UNION ALL  
   SELECT t1.*  
   FROM [I_DEPARTMENT] t1 INNER JOIN  
   Vals1 v ON t1.DEPARTMENT_ID = v.PARENT_ID  

 )  

 select @count=count(*) from Vals1 where is_active = 'N'   

 if @count>0  
 begin  


   RETURN -11  

 end  

  end  

 ;  

  WITH Vals AS (  
   SELECT *  
   FROM [I_DEPARTMENT]  
   WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID in (select Data from  dbo.Split(@DEPARTMENT_ID,','))  
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT t1.*  
   FROM [I_DEPARTMENT] t1 INNER JOIN  
   Vals v ON t1.PARENT_ID = v.DEPARTMENT_ID  
   )  


   UPDATE I_Department  
   SET Is_Active= @Is_Active     
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN (select DEPARTMENT_ID from Vals )  



    END
```

Please suggest me how can I achieve the desired output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this from what i understood.

```
SELECT @DepartmentID = DepartmentID FROM Child_Departments WHERE Child_ID = @Child_ID

IF (@DepartmentID IS NULL OR @DepartmentID = '')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'The child id does not have DepartmentID'
    RETURN
END

SELECT @Is_Active = Is_Active FROM Departments WHERE DepartmentID = @DepartmentID

IF @Is_Active = 'Yes' 

UPDATE Child_Departments
SET Is_Active = 'Yes'
WHERE Child_ID = @Child_ID
```